# Commands on my .bash_profile aren't recognized when using `:!cmd` on OSX 10.11 using mvim

Tags: vimrc

Why are the commands on my `.bash_profile` not recognized? I tried using both `set shell=/bin/bash\` and `set shell=/bin/bash\ -i` - none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell which executes your command isn't a login shell, so it doesn't load .bash_profile. One hack for getting it to work (even though most people I've seen recommend against it) is: `:set shellcmdflag=-i` in your .vimrc.

I don't recall why it was recommended against, but when I've done it, Vim tends to randomly get put in the background like `CTRL+z` was pressed.

Here's a previous StackOverflow answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases

Comment: Why'd they recommend against it?

Comment: I'll see if I can find it...